# Python Xpath how to check if a element exist?

Tags: python, xpath

I'm writing a simple python web crawler.I try to use the Xpath to filter the page.Here's part of target page.

```
<p class="mt12">21 
  <span class="line">|</span>low 18
  <span class="line">|</span>north
  <span class="line">|</span>2016
</p>

 <p class="mt12">22
  <span class="line">|</span>low 19
  <span class="line">|</span>2018
</p>
```

Some items have three description and some have four.How to use Xpath to check whether element exist?I want to extract all of the descriptions like:

```
# if element four exists get span four
good['year'] = goods.xpath("p[@class='mt12']/text()[4]")
# else get span three
good['year'] = goods.xpath("p[@class='mt12']/text()[3]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use below code:

```
good['year'] = goods.xpath("p[@class='mt12']/text()[4]") or goods.xpath("p[@class='mt12']/text()[3]")
```

It should return you `text()[4]` if it's exists (not empty string) or `text()[3]` otherwise

*Update*

In case `"p[@class='mt12']/text()[4]"` expression returns you exception, you can apply `try`/`except` block as below:

```
try:
    good['year'] = goods.xpath("p[@class='mt12']/text()[4]")
except IndexError:
    good['year'] = goods.xpath("p[@class='mt12']/text()[3]")
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.It returns error.`list index out of range`

Comment: Usually `XPath` shouldn't return an exception in case no nodes were matched... But if so, try updated answer